# Omxplayer failing on Raspberry pi 3 with Jessie OS

Tags: raspbian-jessie, noobs, pi-3, omxplayer

On my Raspberry Pi 2 running Wheezy, I have a php if statement that if true

```
echo exec('/usr/bin/X11/omxplayer -o local --win "0 0 1680 1080" /var/www/xxx/thisvideo.mp4 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null');
```

I also have OMXPlayer running a startup movie, both run fine. But I on my Raspberry Pi 3 running Jessie, I have the same statement, but it won't run the video, the screen flashes like it is trying to start but just goes back to what it was doing. On this Pi I also have the startup movie running with OMXPlayer and it runs fine. Is there something that has changed from Wheezy to Jessie that I'm overlooking?

Comment: I have voted to close the question, because Jessie and OMXPlayer now are both deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are on OMXPlayer version 3.6 and not 3.7? 3.7 is listed [here](http://omxplayer.sconde.net/) as the most recent, which is a version ahead of what ships with Noobs (via Aptitude). I ask because I was totally unable to get OMXPlayer to reliably play video until I uninstalled it from Aptitude, downloaded the `deb` file from the site up there and installed. I am now reliably able to play videos via OMXPlayer.

Comment: It might be a trouble with versions, but that does not explain why it works in other scenarios.

Comment: I don't have an explanation, but I do have a method for getting OMXplayer to work in Raspberry Pi 3 under Jessie which is:

1. get rid of 3.6 from aptitude
2. download 3.7 from [here](http://omxplayer.sconde.net/)
3. install 3.7 via `wget` and `dpkg`
4. play video reliably again

So, are you sure you are not on 3.6?

Comment: That was one of the first things that I tried.  I got 3.7 from that locations as well